# Hidden pages in LaTeX

Tags: pdf, page

I'm trying to create a resume that would be one page only with 'hidden pages' (so the document would have a number of pages of which only main page would be shown). The idea is that on the main page I would have certain sections, let's say: publications section, which would be hyperlinked and only when user clicks the hyperlink the pdf would switch to the page, where there is the additional content that I want. But! I don't want the reader to be able to navigate through all pages, I want as a default to show only the main page and all of the other 'subpages' would be hidden.
Is it possible in LaTeX?

Comment: I think it is just possible in presentations.

Comment: Have a look at the attachfile2 package. This allows you to add "pdf attachments", so you could have a pdf file for each page and link them from within the document (in which they are included).

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to TeX.SE.! As far as I know, a `.pdf` or `.dvi` file can not have such a functionality (for whole pages). But it can have it for comments... something that I suppose is not enough for you.  If you open any pdf (or dvi) by using any viewer of your system, you will see that all the pages are visible. So, the I don't think you can do it with just a pdf or dvi file. What I think can work for you, is to create the other pages in a site (a free site of wordpress or a google site would be ok for it) and add in your pdf hyperlinks to this site's hidden pages (that the user can't find through navigation in the page -this is possible in both wordpress sites and google sites-)

An example of a latex code using this functionality, is just any simple (or complicated) template for your CV and the links would work with:

1. `\usepackage{hyperref}` in your preamble, and
2. `\href{www.<YourPage>.wordpress.com/<HiddenPageNonFromNavigation>/}{My Publications}` where "My Publications" is the words that will appear in the pdf file and will drive the user in your "Hidden Page".

The problem is that the reader has to read online this pdf in order to "find" your hidden links, but I think it is the only way.

PS: Hyperlinks to other pdfs could be possible too as a second thought and you could sent a zipped file with all the pdfs, but then the user could open them (and may be could chose one of them as his first choice). You could just use dummy names for these pdfs and a clear name for your main file (preferable a name starting with `0` or `1` in order to be shown as first file in most folder settings of any operating system)

Comment: Imagine I'm a less tech-savvy recruiter. I get a collection of zipped PDFs with funny looking names like that, I suspect he sender of being an unsuccessful phisher in desguise of an applicant. None of those documents will be opened and that sorry donkey's email address is listed as junk company-wide. :D One Trojan down! Neeext!

Comment: Yes @thymaro... You are right, and this is why I left that as a PS. Also had thought about presentations with repeated pages (to protect from left clicking) but the same (your described) reason and the fact that reading in non-presentation mode will be possible... made me not even to add this way (+1 to your comment)... but I am just trying to show some alternatives... and not to recommend one of them.

Comment: I just wanted to lower the chance of any serious applicants to lower their chances of getting hired with a phishy looking setup ;) it might give somebody ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I will look further into all the options. It's a pity you can't do it directly in LaTeX :)

Answer (score 7):

One solution could be `xr-hyper`:

[image: mwe]

curriculum.tex:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\externaldocument{001}
\externaldocument{002}
\usepackage{nameref}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\section*{\em\centering Curriculum vitae}
\ref{pub}. \nameref{pub} \dotfill \pageref{pub}\par 
\ref{books}. \nameref{books}\dotfill \pageref{books}\par 
\ref{jobs}. \nameref{jobs} \dotfill \pageref{jobs}\par 
\end{document}
```

001.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Publications}\label{pub}\lipsum[1-20]
\subsection{Books}\label{books}
\lipsum[21-30]
\end{document}
```

002.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\setcounter{page}{23}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\begin{document}
\section{Experience}\label{jobs}  Lore ipsum ...
\end{document}
```

Note that you must compile main document at least twice but after compiling each child document.

Obviously, this way anyone could see that there are child files (001.pdf, 002.pdf, etc.) in the directory. You could try to hidden them a bit, using a subdirectory for child files (warning: not tested) or use invisible/hidden filenames or even hiden subfolders, but consider the thymaro's comments:  *Hide the merits ... for what? surely, there's something fishy here. Where is the trash icon?*

Answer (score 1):

As other answers pointed out there is no way to do what you ask exactly.

As an alternative, you could have some "optional" sections in your resume, and compile both a long and a short version (with/without the optional sections). This way you can choose which version to send depending on who you send it to, or send both versions and let the reader decide which one they want to read.

A simple way to achieve this is to define a new command (or environment) for optional sections:

```
\newcommand{\optional}[1]{#1}
%\newcommand{\optional}[1]{}
```

Use this command for the optional parts, e.g.:

```
\optional{
   ...
   These details won't appear in the short version
   ...
}
```

To compile the short version, manually change the definition of the command so that it doesn't show the content:

```
%\newcommand{\optional}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\optional}[1]{}
```

Of course this is not a very sophisticated approach, but I found it convenient for my resume.

Comment: The [comment package](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment?lang=en) does this more systematically. I use it heavily.